# How do you get git integration working with m2eclipse?

Tags: git, m2eclipse

I'm trying out m2eclipse, and I see it has some functionality to checkout a maven project directly from SCM. According to [this page](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating.html#creating-sect-checking-out-scm), it supports a whole bunch of different SCM tools including git. However, when I get to that "Checkout as Maven project from SCM" dialog, the drop-down that lets you choose the type of repository is devoid of choices. There must be some additional component or something I haven't installed. As a shot in the dark, I tried installing EGit, but that didn't do it. Help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of Eclipse Indigo, there is a link at the bottom of the "Checkout as Maven project from SCM" dialog to "Find more SCM connectors in the M2E Marketplace." So the steps are now:

1. File->New->Project...
2. Choose "Maven/Checkout Maven Projects from SCM" from the list. This type of project should be available if you installed the Eclipse for Java Developers package.
3. On the bottom right of the dialog that pops up, click "M2E Marketplace." [image: Checkout as Maven project from SCM dialog]
4. Search the m2e marketplace for "egit". Note that searching for "git" doesn't work.
5. Go through the installation steps, which involve restarting eclipse.
6. Do steps 1 and 2 again. Now you should be able to choose "git" in the checkout dialog.
7. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the current level of integration between m2eclipse and egit.
It [wasn't great back in March 2010](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Failing-to-check-out-a-maven-project-from-github-td139657.html).

In any case, [Maven SCM provider for Git](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html) can help.