# Eclipse and Maven via command line

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

I can create a simple Maven application in the Eclipse IDE (version 3.71) by skipping archetype selection that contains folders (**Edit 2** as well as other folders):

```
src/main/resources
src/test/resources
```

These folders are missing if I use the command line. I have been using the maven guide to create a maven project for my eclipse IDE using the command line as specified on the [Maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html)

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=guide.ide.eclipse -DartifactId=guide-ide-eclipse
```

How do I mimic Eclipse's behaviour via the command line? I have tried to find the correct archetypeID and add the arguments to no success.

**Edit1**

The resulting maven project is contained in a git repository so I can import the project as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869815/importing-a-maven-project-into-eclipse-from-git/7269917#comment15380158_7269917)

Comment: Properbly the Eclipse workspace folder is not the same as the project folder.

Comment: always use the terminal via the command line for this, do not trust the IDE, just like this:
mvn eclipse: eclipse, mvn clean install etc. Gold tip: command line

Answer (score 5):

This inconsistency problem is long identified with the Eclipse plugin for Maven.If you use the Eclipse IDE for executing Maven commands, It will not work exactly the way that Maven works with command line. So what most developers do is, run the maven commands from command line and then execute

`mvn eclipse:eclipse`

to update eclipse project. After that you go back to Eclipse IDE and refresh your project. then your project will be updated as per the changes done via command line.

It is also recommended to update your pom.xml with following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I kind of disagree with "what most developers do" part... I'm not sure if I'm off the mark here, but everywhere I know, [m2e eclipse-maven integration](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) has been used, and with that there hasn't been any need to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (note that it's `mvn`, not maven).

Comment: but all of this is beside the point I think - the OP wanted to know how to get what eclipse does to command line, not the other way around, right?

Comment: My problem is not with importing the project into eclipse so I've not used 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' command. I am more confused that using Eclipse without using an Archetype (skipping archetype selection) I arrive at different folder layout to the command line. I assumed Eclipse must have an Archetype for the simple project but I could not find it. I have tried your solution @Kltis but it has not had the desired effect.