# Download Hadoop source configure it on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I need to find full instructions on how to download the Hadoop source code and how to configure it on Eclipse Kepler version.

Answer (score 1):

You would need eclipse plugin to run MR jobs from eclipse directly to a Hadoop cluster. Follow this [link](https://github.com/itsamiths/hadoop-eclipse-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop source code is here.

```
https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common
```

You can download a complete Zip from GitHub, but eventually you should learn to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/)

Hadoop is a maven project so you can import it using [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869815/importing-a-maven-project-into-eclipse-from-git).

If what you really want (and I suspect it is) is to learn how to set up Hadoop in a single node and start wiring Map Reduce jobs I liked [this tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).