# Eclipse's hadoop plugin not showing up on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, hadoop-plugins

I'm trying to set hadoop up on Ubuntu to develop a project. 
I'm using Ubuntu 12, hadoop 0.18, java6 and Eclipse. Ubuntu OS is running on a virtual machine (VMware).

I installed hadoop by following this guide: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/ 
and everything works fine.

Then I saw Hadoop provides a plugin for Eclipse. So, by following this guide: http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/13.5%20-%20copy%20hadoop%20plugin.html (even if it's for Windows)
I copied the plugin from '*hadoop/contrib/eclipse-plugin*' to '*/usr/share/eclipse/plugins*'.

Here's the problem: when I start Eclipse (as root), it looks like the plugin  is not loaded! In fact, inside Eclipse's "open perspective" window the voice 'mapReduce' is not showing up (as the guide states).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have an eclipse plugin which is not compatible with your eclipse. Try this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541820/download-hadoop-source-configure-it-on-eclipse/21591847#21591847)

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse as hduser. Even if Eclipse starts for root, the plugin only shows up for the user who has installed it.

To login as hduser, type:

`su hduser`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using hadoop 0.18 - you should go for hadoop 0.18 plugin for eclipse and not for a hadoop 0.19. For the plugin jar you can goto this site :- http://code.google.com/p/hadoopcs492/source/browse/ben_single_node/hadoop-0.18.0/contrib/eclipse-plugin