# How to change the version of Hadoop eclipse plugin from 2.6.0 to 2.7.1

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed the Hadoop 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in pseudo distributed mode. Now I want to connect hadoop with eclipse by using hadoop-eclipse-plugin. But the plugin that I have is version 2.6.0 which is not compatible with hadoop 2.7.1.

So Is there any way to change the version of hadoop-eclipse-plugin from 2.6.0 to 2.7.1.

Comment: Not compatible in what way?

Comment: For compatibility the plugin version should be same as hadoop version. ie for hadoop 2.7.1 the plugin should be of version 2.7.1.

Comment: Sure, but what happens when you try running it?

Comment: Open PRs have been there for years... https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin/pulls

Comment: when i copy the plugin 2.6.0 to the plugin directory of eclipse(oxygen) it does not show up in the perspective section of eclipse IDE.

Comment: Sounds like an Eclipse problem, not a Hadoop version compatibility problem

Comment: the compatibility problem is also discussed here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666271/eclipses-hadoop-plugin-not-showing-up-on-ubuntu

Comment: Sure but the "2.6.0" refers to Hadoop itself, not any Eclipse compatible version number

Comment: sorry ... i was referring you the third answer in that link

Comment: I will check your provided link. Any way thank you bro.