# How to import project in 3rd party repository as library for eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, wso2

I have very less experience with java. However when I'm following WSO2 document (https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45952633), I have to import external libraries from a git repository (https://github.com/wso2/carbon-commons). I build it then try to add to my project through java build path (after built step so many projects were built so I add every projects to my project). Then I try to use those libraries from my project but it seems not working. Am i miss any step(s) or am i in a completely wrong path?

Comment: Is it a Jar or a project?

Comment: It is a project

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869815/importing-a-maven-project-into-eclipse-from-git ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing a Maven project into Eclipse from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869815/importing-a-maven-project-into-eclipse-from-git)